# Share files with other users (Django)

Tags: python, html, django, redis

Description About the application:
The main idea of this app is to create projects and share uploaded files with other users with permission.
So:
after creating the project( which is a Project module also),
When any user uploads his file to the Django database, he can make this file visible to other users or not(this depends on his choice).
This is the models:

```
class File(models.Model):
    file_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    file = models.FileField(storage=file_storage, max_length=100)
    project_owner = models.ForeignKey(Project, on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='project_owner')
    projects_accessed = models.ManyToManyField(Project)
```

And this is the Project Module also:

```
class Project(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    task = models.ForeignKey(Task, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(UserProfile, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

This is the kind of prototype i want to create!!
[Image Proto type](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NldWo.png)

So, please any ideas or how can solve this kind of problem?
Thank you in advance !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find the solution maybe it can help someone:
make a relationship between the project and the file uploaded
and apply a filter to it:

```
File.objects.filter(project_owner__user=project.user)
```